# Excision of cofibrations

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

**EDIT.** The answer is a resounding NO! ^^ there are obvious conter examples : take $A=B=\lbrace 0\rbrace$, and $X=\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R^2}=Y$, then $H_*(X,X-A)=H_*(\Bbb R,\Bbb R-0)=\Bbb Z[1]$ is $\Bbb Z$ in degree $1$, and $H_*(Y,Y-B)=H_*(\Bbb R^2,\Bbb R^2-0)=\Bbb Z[2]$ is $\Bbb Z$ in degree $2$. I feel silly !

---

Consider the following setup : I have a commutative diagram of spaces and maps
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
B & \hookrightarrow & Y\\
\sim\uparrow\phantom{\sim} && \phantom{\sim}\uparrow\sim\\
A & \hookrightarrow & X\\
\end{array}
$$
where $A\hookrightarrow X$ and $B\hookrightarrow Y$ are (Hurewicz) cofibrations, and the map of pairs $f:(X,A)\to(Y,B)$ induces a homotopy equivalence between $A$ and $B$, and between $X$ and $Y$.

Under these circumstances, it is for example known ([prop 1.15 here](http://cqfd.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/cqfd/files/shared/projets/igat/Homotopy%20theory%20-%20Hadi.pdf)) that the $f$ is a homotopy equivalence of pairs.

> Is there necessarily an isomorphism of relative (co)homology
>   $$
> h(X,X-A)\simeq h(Y,Y-B)
> $$
>   ($h$ is singular (co)homology)

Of course there are immediate problems : while $f$ sends $A$ into $B$, it need not send $X-A$ into $Y-B$, although it could happen to do so in the case I'm considering, I haven't checked but it doesn't seem unreasonable.

If It can help, all spaces involved are Hausdorff and so $A$ and $B$ are closed subspaces of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and most likely locally compact.